# GCS get blob filename

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to understand the syntax for filename in the following google snippit...

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('remote-file')
```

My question is how is the remote-file to be specified?  Would it be 'my-bucket/the/path/to/filename' or 'the/path/to/filename'?  When I try the first way, nothing is returned... not even an error.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you get the bucket

```
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
```

Then, simple specify the FULL path inside the bucket (with the bucket name because you call the method on the bucket object)

```
blob = bucket.get_blob('the/path/to/filename')
```

Comment: So that is what I'm doing, but blob gets the value of "None"... any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: My mistake reading your answer- yes, removed the bucket-id and it works.  Thanks!